# Argument 3 passed to twig_template_from_string() must be of the type string or null

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I did an update of my Symfony version (3.4.26 -> 3.4.37) and since this update I have the following error:

> Type error: Argument 3 passed to twig_template_from_string() must be
>   of the type string or null, object given, called in
>   /var/www/html/var/cache/dev/twig/09/0965cdf4a4c2728abc6e3a7f526f3e5ee9321e47e22a23568e44c13454b5ad97.php
>   on line 132

Are there some updates of this function between versions ?

Comment: What is your twig version in composer.json ?

Comment: My twig version : v2.12.5

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have given it's going to be hard to understand what exactly happened. However...

1. open `/var/www/html/var/cache/dev/twig/09/0965cdf4a4c2728abc6e3a7f526f3e5ee9321e47e22a23568e44c13454b5ad97.php` on line 132
2. Scrol higher line by line until you see a comment like

```
 // line 3
```

Now we know this is about line three of file X, but which file is X? Let's find out.... navigate to the top of the file until you find something like

```
/* @WebProfiler/Collector/config.html.twig */
```

This is going to be just above the class declaration in your cache file. GREAT, now you know what source file was it.

3. Open the source file at line 3 (or whatever the line caused you trouble)
   Now you should know what was the object and why it's not the thing the function described.

I see there was php 7.4 compatibility implemented  ( 
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blame/v3.4.37/composer.json#L23
)
which means some parameter and typehinting changes could occur.

If that doesn't solve the issue for you, simply add another question that's more descriptive and avoid asking people about your cache files which we will never have :)

Good luck!